# Consistency strength about Ramsey M-rank and Mahlo-Ramsey cardinal

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

In the website "Cantor's attic", there are a long list of large cardinal axioms arranged by consistency strength.

In the list, "α-Mahlo Ramsey" is placed higher than "Ramsey M-rank", however, I can't find any reference that compares the consistency strength between them.

So, how could we prove, for example, con(ZFC+1-Mahlo Ramsey) implies con(ZFC+there is a cardinal κ with Ramsey M-rank κ+)?